# Accessing request body with ZombieJS

Tags: node.js, zombiejs

I'm using ZombieJS v4 (4.0.13), and am trying to access the client's request body, since some tests require me to monitor the fields that are automatically sent via client forms.
While I can access all the query-string fields by using the pipeline's addHandler hook, I can't seem to read the request body in order to extract body post params.

Working with the **response** body is easy - I can access it from the pipeline by waiting for the response to consume. But the request body always appears as null, with *_bodyUsed = true*, so I can't wait for it in the same manner.

Anyone knows of a way I can access the sent request body, either via the pipeline, or somewhere else?

10x

Comment: Found a possible solution:
at pipeline.js,
at function makeHTTPRequest()
inside return consumeBody.then(function (body) {
The consumed body is used in the new httpRequest, but never re-assigned to the original request, which causes it to remain as _bodyUsed=true, but with body = null.

Adding request.body = body; just before creating the new httpRequest resolves the issue, and makes the body accessible via the pipeline.